# Trying to remove roman numerals and numbers from a <String> arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, list, numbers

I'm trying to remove things like "I." "II." "279" (page numbers and chapters) etc from a text file of the story "robin hood". So far I cant figure out how to get rid of the numbers (the `arraylist` is a string)

```
for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {

    if (list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("I.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("II.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("III.") || list.get(x).equals("IV.") || list.get(x).equals("V.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("VI.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("VII.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("VIII.") || list.get(x).equals("IX.") || list.get(x).equals("X.") || list.get(x).equals("XI.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("XII.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("XIII.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("XIV.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("XV.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("XVI.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("XVII.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("XVIII.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("XIX.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("XX.") || list.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase("XXI.")) {
        list.remove(x);
        numWords--;
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        if (list.get(x) == y) {
            list.remove(x);
            numWords--;
        }


    }

}
```

I'm aware there's an error where I'm looking to see if `y == list.get(x)` but I cant really think of another way to remove a number.

Comment: [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) should fit well here. I used a code based on regex a few months ago to convert roman numbers to regular numbers, I'll try to find it (though it is MUCH more complicated in my case, I used it to parse a very noisy text from the 17th century :| )

Comment: yeah list is ArrayList<String>

Comment: and each element in the `list` is a word?

Comment: no there are numbers and items like [,],/ etc.
im mainly focused on getting rid of the numbers though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of having that massive `if` statement you could perhaps do something like

```
if (list.get(x).toUpperCase().matches("[IVXLCDM]+\\.")) {...}
```

`[IVXLCDM]` matches either `I`, `V` .. `M` - so `[IVXLCDM]+` matches any continuous string of these characters. The `\.` ensures that the string is ended with a period.

Now if you wanted to match numbers you could use the regular expression `"\\d+"`, and apply the same idea as above.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use regular expressions to find out lines that match numbers or roman numerals.
The regex (short for regular expression) you need is probably something like:

```
^([0-9]+)|([IVXLCM]+)\\.?$
```

to check both arabic and roman numerals.
Here's a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) on regular expressions, which gives you a sample application to try out regexes, and explains the syntax.

Comment: ill look at the tutorial, but im only in my second year of learning java t school- so i havent done something with that syntax yet. thanks though!

Comment: no problem: regexes are an invaluable tool in the programmer arsenal, consider studying it as soon as possible.